# Elasticsearch dynamic choose query

Tags: elasticsearch

When querying with the should command, I am wondering if there is a way to make only the responses of queries with higher scores come out.

I'm sorry I'm not good at English, please understand it.
Let's assume I have such data

#### index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### data

```
{
  "_index" : "dismisstest",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "chul"
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "dismisstest",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "wedul"
  }
}
```

#### query (example..)

```
GET dismisstest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "wedul",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "chul",
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### want result (Document using only wedul query)

```
{
  "_index" : "dismisstest",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "wedul"
  }
}
```

The above query is a simple example, but I want to use only the query that returns the document with a high score among the two should queries. Is there any possible way??

Comment: do you want to get the document having the highest score ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using dis_max or function_score query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html#query-dsl-dis-max-query

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query

Comment: I am not sure how to extract only the result of the first query with the highest score from the above data with the dis_max query. Could you please give me an example?